# How can I dynamically name buttons in a jquery modal script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script that's used to create a modal with buttons. I just have the first lines below:

```
$.modal = function(options)
    {
        var settings = $.extend({}, $.modal.defaults, options),
            root = getModalDiv(),

            // Vars for resizeFunc and moveFunc
            winX = 0,
            winY = 0,
            contentWidth = 0,
            contentHeight = 0,
            mouseX = 0,
            mouseY = 0,
            resized, content = '', contentObj;
```

and then later:

```
    var buttonsFooter = false;
    $.each(settings.buttons, function(key, value)
    {
        // Button zone
        if (!buttonsFooter)
        {
            buttonsFooter = $('<div class="block-footer align-'+settings.buttonsAlign+'"></div>').insertAfter(contentBlockWrapper);
        }
        else
        {
            // Spacing
            buttonsFooter.append('&nbsp;');
        }
```

Here's the way I create the modal:

```
$.modal({
                    title: title,
                    closeButton: true,
                    content: content,
                    complete: function () {
                        applyTemplateSetup();
                        $($('#main-form')).updateTabs();
                    },
                    width: 900,
                    resizeOnLoad: true,
                    buttons: {
                        'Submit' : function () {
                            formSubmitHandler($('#main-form'));
                        }
                    }
                });
```

What I would like to do is to use this script to create my modal with buttons and dynamically assign the button name. However when I tried replacing 'Submit' with the name of a javascript variable it didn't work. Does anyone have any idea how I could do what I need?

Answer (score 1):

The reason replacing `'Submit'` with a variable name doesn't work is because the quotes aren't needed when defining an object in that manner (unless the name contains some special characters). `var obj = { 'Submit': function() { } }` is exactly the same thing as `var obj = { Submit: function() { } }`.

You'll notice that you're already omitting the quotes like this in the object you're passing to `$.modal()`.

However, while you can't write

```
var myVariable = 'abc';
var obj = { myVariable: 3 };
```

... and expect `obj.abc` to exist (`obj.myVariable` will exist), you *can* write

```
var myVariable = 'abc';
var obj[myVariable]  = 3;
```

... and `obj.abc` *will* exist.

Thus, you could solve your problem in the following manner:

```
var buttons = { };

buttons[variableName] = function () {
   formSubmitHandler($('#main-form'));
};

$.modal({
   ...
   buttons: buttons
});
```

Comment: +1, you beat me and offered an answer which requires a little less code modification. And your edit attempts to explain some of the principles behind it.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** David Hedlund beat me to answering, and offered a similar answer which involves a little less code modification. He suggests only breaking out the buttons options instead of the entire options var. **End Edit**

First, break the options out into a variable:

```
var modalOpts = {
    title: title,
    closeButton: true,
    content: content,
    complete: function () {
        applyTemplateSetup();
        $($('#main-form')).updateTabs();
    },
    width: 900,
    resizeOnLoad: true,
    buttons: {
        'Submit' : function () {
            formSubmitHandler($('#main-form'));
        }
    }
};

$.modal(modalOpts);
```

Then break the button in question out of the options, and use square bracket notation to access and write the property:

```
var dynamicButtonName = 'Submit'; //Or whatever

var modalOpts = {
    title: title,
    closeButton: true,
    content: content,
    complete: function () {
        applyTemplateSetup();
        $($('#main-form')).updateTabs();
    },
    width: 900,
    resizeOnLoad: true,
    buttons: {}
};

modalOpts.buttons[dynamicButtonName] = function () {
    formSubmitHandler($('#main-form'));
};

$.modal(modalOpts);
```